# HTML onchange isn't firing Google's htmlservice

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn how Google's htmlservice works. I've taken their [example code for the form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and modified like this:

```
var whichYear='';
var whichClass='';
function processForm(formObject) {
Logger = BetterLog
           .useSpreadsheet('0AiWcWJrA0KCpdHB2X2pYQ04xSXNDVnNtTnBOX1RRd1E');

Logger.log('in processForm enumerating properties');
for(var prop in formObject){
     Logger.log('Entered processForm - prop::'+prop+'--value--  '+formObject[prop]+':: ');
     if( prop == 'yearSelect')
     {
       if (formObject[prop] != 'nochange')
         whichYear=formObject[prop];
     }
     else
       if(prop == 'classSelect'){
         if(formObject[prop]!= 'nochange')
           whichClass = formObject[prop];
       }
     if (whichClass != '' && whichYear!='')
       tallyClass();
   }
  return 'a string';
} 
function tallyClass(){
Logger = BetterLog
           .useSpreadsheet('0AiWcWJrA0KCpdHB2X2pYQ04xSXNDVnNtTnBOX1RRd1E');
 Logger.log('Entered tallyClass - whichYear::'+whichYear+'--whichClass--'+whichClass+':: ');

}
```

The associated html looks like this:

```
<script>
  function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Please choose which group to tally.</a>';
  }
</script>

<form>
  <select name="yearSelect" id="yearSelect" onchange="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" >
   <option value="nochange">Please select a year</option>
   <option value="2006">2006</option>
   <option value="2010">2010</option>
</select>
<p>
<select name="classSelect" id="classSelect" onchange="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" >
   <option value="nochange">Please select a class</option>
   <option value="oldbie">oldbie</option>
   <option value="newbie">newbie</option>
 </select>
</form>
 <p>
<div id="output"> </div>
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

I'm trying to avoid using a submit button so that I can respond to menu selection events dynamically. Selecting which year fires off the formProcess function as expected but the identical class selection menu does nothing.

What I expect to see is when one menu is selected, I get an onchange event call. When I've received two onchange event calls, I'll process the user's selection.

I'm fairly certain that I can just do an onSubmit call and be done with it but I'd really like to understand why I never get an onchange call if the second menu is selected.

Is the onchange event only attachable to a single element?

Comment: add apps script tags as this appears to be

Comment: It should at least log Enteres Processform. Multiple google.script.runs should work fine. They both show the same form though. You could not see the difference.

Comment: Check the p tags also.

Comment: @Riel I agree that the log should show ProcessForm was entered but it doesn't. Only a change to the first menu fires the onChange. I don't really care if I know which menu fired the onchange event because when it does fire on the first menu, I get the second menu's value.

Comment: @Riel Thanks! Your comment about the p tag led to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the HTML between the two dropdown menus from

```
<p>
```

to

```
<p></p>
```

to close the paragraph tag  fixed the problem.

The error slipped past the renderer so the dialog box rendered correctly but didn't get past the code that monitors DOM events. Hence no onChange event from the second dropdown.